# How to check and run math expression using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Javascript function that will take a mathematical expression and apply it to a predefined number, for example:

```
var myNum = 10;

function EQ(eq){
// code here 
}
```

For example the input should me something like this:

```
EQ("*100/10"); //output 100
EQ("+100");    //output will be 110
EQ("-+=1");    //output false
```

Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this?

Comment: For future readers wondering the same thing as Tin, jQuery was part of the original title and tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably work `eval()` into a simple solution. For instance:

```
var myNum = 10;

function EQ(eq) { return eval(myNum+eq); }

alert( EQ("*100/10") ); // outputs 100
```

I'd encourage you to expand upon this by implementing a `try-catch` and handling exceptions.

Comment: thanks a lot, but EQ("100/10"); // output 1010 // how to output an error ??

Comment: @From.ME You are changing syntax on me here. All of your examples started with an operator in the value passed to `EQ()`. In the data you provided, and in my solution, it is assumed the first char will always (without variance) be an operator. If you pass in `100/10` then the evaluated expression will be `10100/10`, which is `1010`.

Comment: With regards to error-handling, here is some information on the `Try...Catch` in Javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple expression evaluator:

```
function evalExpression(text)
{
  var tokens = text.split(" ");

  var output = [];
  var operators = [];

  var reNumber = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
  var reOperator = /^[\/\+\*\-]$/;
  var precedence = { "+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2 };

  for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i)
  {
    var t = tokens[i];
    if (reNumber.test(t))
      output.push(Number(t));
    else if (reOperator.test(t))
    {
      while (operators.length && precedence[t] <= precedence[operators[operators.length - 1]])
      {
        output.push(operators.pop());
      }

      operators.push(t);
    }
    else if (t == "(")
      operators.push(t);
    else if (t == ")")
    {
      while (operators.length && operators[operators.length - 1] != "(")
        output.push(operators.pop());

      if (!operators.length) return false;

      operators.pop();    
    }
    else 
      return false;
  }

  while (operators.length)
    output.push(operators.pop());

  var result = [];

  for (i = 0; i < output.length; ++i)
  {
    t = output[i];
    if (reNumber.test(t))
      result.push(t);
    else if (t == "(" || result.length < 2)
      return false;
    else 
    {
      var lhs = result.pop();
      var rhs = result.pop();

      if (t == "+") result.push(lhs + rhs);
      if (t == "-") result.push(lhs - rhs);
      if (t == "*") result.push(lhs * rhs);
      if (t == "/") result.push(lhs / rhs);
    }
  }

  return result.pop();
}
```

It supports numbers and `+ - * / ( )`. Tokens must be separated by a single space, e.g.: "1 * ( 2 + 3 )"

Anyway, that's the type of code you'd need if you didn't want to use `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
function EQ(input) {
  try {
    var ret = Number(eval('(0+(' + input + '))'));
    return isNaN(ret) ? null : ret;
  } catch(err) {
  }
  return null;
}
```

You can replace the null default with a literal false if you like...