# Testing an equation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I test if a mathematical expression is true?

```
var equation = "1 + 1 = 2";
if (equation === true){
  document.write("1 + 1 = 2");
}else{
  document.write("1 + 1 =/= 2");
}
```

For obvious reasons, this code ^^^ doesn't work, but I just wanted to know if there was a function that would do this; evaluate a mathematical expression then return its verity as a boolean (true/false).

Comment: I'd suggest `eval()` but you'd also need to change `=` to `==` for that to work properly.

Comment: You could eval it *(but for the `=` as noted above)*, but what's the actual situation? This feels like an XY Problem. Otherwise, you could manually parse the string.

Comment: @I Hate Lazy: I am in fact working on a sort of equation solver so that I can get the hang of for and while loops. I just would like to know if such a function existed to test equalities like the one I previously stated.

Comment: @user1892304, why not just log values to the console, or use assertions? `console.assert(1 + 1 == 2, 'oh no what has happened to math?')`

Comment: Have a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421362/how-to-check-and-run-math-equation-using-javascript .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `eval`; but note that it requires JavaScript notation, not an ad-hoc notation:

```
var equation = "1 + 1 == 2";         // note: `==`, not `=`
if (eval(equation)){
  document.write("1 + 1 = 2");
}else{
  document.write("1 + 1 =/= 2");
}
```

This approach has the downside of not being very "safe", since the `eval`'d string can contain any JavaScript code whatsoever. That greatly restricts the set of situations in which it makes sense to use it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning security concerns.  `eval()` can be dangerous when feeding user input into it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a method that simply checks if two values add up as expected:

```
function addsUp(a, b, x) {
 return a + b === x;
}

if (addsUp(1, 1, 2)){
  document.write("1 + 1 = 2");
}else{
  document.write("1 + 1 =/= 2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var equation = eval("1+1==2");
```

More details here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP

Comment: -0.25 for w3schools.  Seriously, there are much less misleading sites out there.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this thread : [Equation (expression) parser with precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence)

But consider that what you're doing is pretty complicated unless you can break it down into some rules.

If it is always in the format of `X (+-/*) Y = Z` then you can strip out the information using regular expressions or a bunch of targeted string replacements. If it needs to cope with `A + B - C = D + Z` (variable numbers of variables on either side of equation) then you will need to look into recursion and/or complicated string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to evaluate your expression:

```
eval("1+1==2")
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
var equation = "1 + 1 = 2";
equation = equation.replace('=','==');
if (eval(equation)){
  document.write("1 + 1 = 2");
}else{
  document.write("1 + 1 =/= 2");
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

if you use userinputs you might have to double the quotes ... otherwise you get an error Invalid left-hand side in assignment

```
var equation = "1 + 1 == 2";

if (eval(equation)){
  document.write("1 + 1 = 2");
}else{
    alert('s');
  document.write("1 + 1 =/= 2");
}​
```